# Use Timer to set Time in UILabel In UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, timer

Trying to set a timer to present time on a label inside a tableViewCell.

Because of my lack of knowledge I am facing this problem.

I am familiar with Timer but I can figure out the most efficient way for this one.

Thanks a lot

Here is my code

```
import UIKit



class WeatherCellLocationCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var localTime: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var cityName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var currentTemp: UILabel!

    func configureCell(weatherPlace : WeatherPlaceData){

        localTime.text = DateFormatter.localizedString(from: weatherPlace.localDate, dateStyle: .none, timeStyle: .short)

        cityName.text = weatherPlace.name
        let temp = Int(weatherPlace.currentTemp)
        currentTemp.text = "\(temp)"

    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()


    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    }

}
```

here I am loading the tableView

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "WeatherCellLocation", for: indexPath) as! WeatherCellLocationCell

            let place = fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath)
         // var timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 60, target: self, selector: #selector(updateTime), userInfo: indexPath, repeats: true)
            cell.configureCell(weatherPlace: place)

            return cell

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

First add the `WeatherPlaceData` object in your cell and put the timer in your cell

```
var currentWeatherPlaceData: WeatherPlaceData?
fileprivate var timeWorking : Bool = false
var timer:Timer?
```

Add a method to update your label

```
func updateTime()
    {
       localTime.text = DateFormatter.localizedString(from: self.currentWeatherPlaceData.localDate, dateStyle: .none, timeStyle: .short)
    }
```

Change your `configureCell` method to this one

```
func configureCell(weatherPlace : WeatherPlaceData){
        self.currentWeatherPlaceData = weatherPlace
        if(!timeWorking)
        {
        localTime.text = DateFormatter.localizedString(from: self.currentWeatherPlaceData.localDate, dateStyle: .none, timeStyle: .short)
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(self.updateTime), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        self.timeWorking = true
        }

        cityName.text = weatherPlace.name
        let temp = Int(weatherPlace.currentTemp)
        currentTemp.text = "\(temp)"

    }
```

And finally adjust the prepare for reuse to avoid issues, restarting your timer

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()
    self.timer.invalidate()
    self.timeWorking = false
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi Reinier. You haven't write the currentWeatherPlaceData = weatherPlace inside configureCell ? if yes I tried that and I still my Label is not showing the time but just the time I am getting from the API.

Comment: No worries thanks a lot by the way for the fast reply. Am still getting the same result though. The timer is not working

Comment: @PS what you have in your self.currentWeatherPlaceData.localDate and what you need to show? a countDown?, please explain, the problem is what are you trying to show, if you show a dateTime even with a timer will show always the same

Comment: I am trying to replicate exactly the same app like weatherApp the Apple has. I am getting a string from the API "2017-08-05 18:15:00" (local time of current Location). I save that on CoreData as Date. and I fetch it and load to the tableViewCell and I am trying to keep it presenting the local time Like the Apples weather app is doing on the locations. When I am printing the self.currentWeatherPlaceData.localDate I get -> Optional(2017-08-05 18:15:00 +0000)

Comment: @PS and why you need a timer then?, I answer assuming that you need a countdown or something like that, then you only need to convert the time to GTM of the desired city and use it in your cell you don't need Timer at all

Comment: @ReinerMelian. I am getting the local time from API directly so I don't have to convert to GMT of local city. What I need ,is to show the change of each minute in the label from the local time that I am getting from the API. Any suggestion? I hope I am explaining correct.

Comment: It seems that you are right. Thanks a lot for the answers and the help! I will make a dif question. P

Comment: @PS i think that what you need is a call for your API every minute, that will get a diferent date value every minute and your app will be updated

Comment: Yes that my current solution , but by checking Apples app even on flight mode the time label is updating. And I guess is not so Cellular - friendly to call every minute(I guess .... I am new in this so I might saying #@$%^#) But thanks a lot Reinier. I guess I can't give somehow a credit for your answers right ?

Comment: @PS, Well the only thing to try is using your Date() for update, but this can be not reliable for the user, I think maybe is a better option put instead of date a label with this info "last updated" at XX:XX hrs I don't know, about credit, not worry I am here to see others people problems and try to help

Answer (score 0):

I would add a Timer to the cell itself that recalculates the time every second.

```
class WeatherCellLocationCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var localTime: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var cityName: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var currentTemp: UILabel!

var timer: Timer?
var weatherPlace: WeatherPlaceData?

func configureCell(weatherPlace : WeatherPlaceData){
    self.weatherPlace = weatherPlace
    setTime()
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(WeatherCellLocationCell.setTime), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

func setTime() {
    localTime.text = DateFormatter.localizedString(from: weatherPlace.localDate, dateStyle: .none, timeStyle: .short)

    cityName.text = weatherPlace.name
    let temp = Int(weatherPlace.currentTemp)
    currentTemp.text = "\(temp)"
}

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
}

override func prepareForReuse() {
    if timer != nil {
        timer?.invalidate()
        timer = nil
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Hi Rool. Thanks for the reply. I tried your code and I am getting the same result as before. The label is not representing a time but just a static label of the result date of the API.